# Cordova `touchend` event behaves differently on iOS

Tags: javascript, cordova

Now as a touch event function

```
$ (`aaa`). on (`touchend`, function () {});
```

I use this structure.

There are 10 buttons, and when you press a particular button strangely, the next time you press another button, the event occurs as if the specific button was pressed.

For example, if you have a button from `$ ("# aaa")` to `$ ("# zzz")`, the other buttons will work normally even after you press another button. However, if you press "zzz" button, event will occur as if "zzz" is pressed again by pressing any of the buttons, and pressing another button will work properly.

The symptom is that once you touch what you touch, the "zzz" button event repeats and appears to work again. Could you tell me what the problem is?

- I am using cordova project and it works well on Android phone, but only on iOS phone ... This happens when I insert the `alert` line in the touch event frame.

Comment: present your code please

Comment: Why do you even need a touch event? Can't you just use clicke if it's a button?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using click instead of touchend.